# Error when trying to implement parallel_for c++11: Error C3019 increment in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, parallel-processing

i am trying to optimise a genetic algorithm, however when using #pragma omp parallel the algorithm runs perfectly.  When i change this to #pragma omp parallel for , i receive the Error C3019 : increment in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form.  the method i am trying to optimize is:

```
vector<unsigned int> decode(genome &gen)
{
    auto num_threads = thread::hardware_concurrency();
    static vector<unsigned int> this_gene(gen.gene_length);
    vector<unsigned int> decoded(NUM_CHARS);

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(num_threads)

        for (unsigned int gene = 0, count = 0; gene < gen.bits.size(); gene += gen.gene_length, ++count)
        {

            for (unsigned int bit = 0; bit < gen.gene_length; ++bit)
                this_gene[bit] = gen.bits[gene + bit];

            unsigned int val = 0;
            unsigned int multiplier = 1;

            for (unsigned int c_bit = this_gene.size(); c_bit > 0; --c_bit)
            {
                val += this_gene[c_bit - 1] * multiplier;
                multiplier *= 2;
            }
            decoded[count] = val;
        }
    return decoded;
}
```

Comment: Your `for` statement doesn't meet the requirements of OpenMP's *canonical loop form*.  The OpenMP specs are at http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/ and will tell you what those requirements are.  I'm sure that a diligent search of SO will also illuminate the matter.

Comment: im very new to all this, and this is not my algorithm i am optimizing, however from my understanding of the OpenMP spec is #pragma omp parallel for (gene, bits, decoded)... am i along the right lines?

Comment: I think you're biting off a lot more than you can chew.  The best advice I can offer is that you start working with much simpler OpenMP programs and learn the basics.  Then, with some solid understanding you will be ready to approach this problem.